# Battleship game - is there a better way to access this text file

Tags: python, list, replace, compare, coordinates

I am making a battleship game that draws its ship coordinates from a text file.

basically

```
0000000
0000100
0000100
0000100
0000100
0000000
0000000
```

I have the ges coordinates reading properly read a file in a method where i can compare the coordinates of the shot to coordinates in the text file.

this is what i have so far

```
for turn in range(30):
  print ("Turn", turn + 1)
  guess_row = int(input("Guess Row:"))
  while guess_row < 1 or guess_row > 10: #or (guess_row.isdigit()) == False:
    guess_row = int(input("You have entered an incorrect coordinate. Please reenter: "))  #guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))
  guess_col = int(input("Guess Column:"))
    while guess_col < 1 or guess_col > 10: #or (guess_row.isdigit()) == False:
      guess_col = int(input("You have entered an incorrect coordinate. Please reenter: "))  #guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))
  myFile = None
  fileName = "map.txt"
  accessMode = "r"

  myFile = open(fileName, accessMode)
  fileContent = myFile.readlines()
  contentList = []
  for c in fileContent[guess_row - 1]:
    contentList = contentList.append(c)
    print(contentList[guess_col - 1])

  print(contentList[guess_col - 1])
  contentList = contentList.replace(',', '')
  print(contentList)
```

any ideas?  I am learning some new stuff in code academy and I am trying different methods to complete the battleship assignment.  I already completed it but what to modify it.

Comment: If this is working code then you should post this to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). This site is for fixing broken code.

Comment: The code doesn't actually work.  There's no comparison of coordiantes nor reactions to each shot.

Comment: @user3524069 Have you tried to add those features? I don't see anywhere in your code where you've attempted this.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea here but you might want to write this differently

1) Read in the text file

2) While you are reading in the file, identify what coordinates ships are located at

3) Store these points in a list. **You should only read in the file once**

4) Take input on where the player would like to shoot

5) Compare player coordinates with viable ship coordinates

6) Inform user if they hit or not

7) Check to see if the ship has sunk or not

Looks good so far, just remember to validate your input and to write your code with efficiency in mind. Good luck!